# Why is string.letters different between python and bpython?

Tags: python, bpython

I ran into a strange issue today. I was using the Python standard library's `string` module's `letters` variable and noticed that the result in bpython was not the same as the result in vanilla python.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and bpython 0.10.1 and virtualenv 1.8.4. Here is what I'm seeing.

```
$ bpython
>>> import string
>>> string.letters
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


$ python
>>> import string
>>> string.letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

I'm not sure that it matters but I'm running this on xubuntu 12.10.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: my guess is they are just different implementations where one said `string.letters = string.ascii_upper + string.ascii_lower` and the other did `string.letters = string.ascii_lower + string.ascii_upper`, I dont think it will have any effect on any of your programs (unless you are trying to do `string.letters[:26]` or something)

Comment: That's odd: using `string.letters` I get the same results as you, but using `string.ascii_letters` I get `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` in both python and bpython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.letters), string.letters is defined as

> The concatenation of the strings lowercase and uppercase described
>   below. The specific value is locale-dependent, and will be updated
>   when locale.setlocale() is called.

So it could be that your locale is different.

Comment: I guess that could be right: `bpython` shows a `locale` of `('en_US', 'UTF-8')` and `python` shows a `locale` of `(None, None)`

Comment: It turns out that the locale does not seem to affect it. I changed the locale in the `python` repl to `('en_US', 'UTF-8')` and `string.letters` was the same.